# Excel vba check if Match function returns NA - macro crashes: Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

Tags: vba, excel

I use a `Match` function to find a specific row with data:

```
Sub test

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hide_rows")
 For i = 2 To 15
   MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0)) 
 Next
End With

End Sub
```

From i = 2 to i=14 it works fine. However the string in `.Cells(15, 1)` excel can't find in a given range which results in  `Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error` error. I tried to fix it by checking if it's `#N/A` first:

```
Sub test

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hide_rows")
 For i = 2 To 15
   MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")), 0)) 
 Next
End With

End Sub
```

It returns `False` for rows 2-14 and still crashed for the 15th.

At the same time if I just calculate the `Match` manually in the sheet and then check if the result is `#N/A` it works fine:

```
Sub test()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hide_rows")
 For i = 2 To 15
   MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(.Cells(i, 7).Value))
 Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Match` you need to check before getting the result if it was successful. You do that by using `If Not IsError(Application.Match...`

***Modified Code***

```
Sub test()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hide_rows")
    For i = 2 To 15
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then

            MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0))

        Else    ' Match failed
            MsgBox "Row " & i & " failed to find a match", vbCritical, "Error"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the return value of `.Cells(i, 7).Value` ***before*** you pass it to `WorksheetFunction.Match`.  I'd also suggest using the VBA function `IsError` instead of `WorksheetFunction.IsNA`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hide_rows")
    For i = 2 To 15
        Dim result As Variant

        result = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        If IsError(result) Then
            'Do whatever
        Else
            MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(result, _
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0))
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: `.Cells(i, 7)` was an example of a correct work of the `IsNa`. In the code you provided the error would occur in the else block - the Match would through it. `.Cells(i, 1).value` is never an error - it's a normal string

Comment: @Ans - You miss the point of using `IsError` instead of `IsNa`. What happens if `.Cells(i, 1).Value` ***is*** an error or is an error other than `#N/A`?  Solid coding protects itself from those eventualities - I just didn't want your next question here to be another "crashes with Error 1004" question.